Не используется дискретная видеокарта на ноутбуке
Не используется дискретная видеокарта в ноутбуке.
Драйвера накатывал используя nvidia-detect
lspci | grep VGA


00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce
RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)

Имеется графика, как от проца, так и сама дискретка
DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL

Выводит, что используется графика от проца.
В настройках видюхи, нету prime настройки
nvidia-prime


bash: nvidia-prime: команда не найдена


Начать стоит с логичного вопроса — драйвер-то установлен? Что такое «настройки видюхи»?

@andreymal Да накатывал через nvidia-detect. "Настройки видюхи" это nvidia-settings

В таком случае дебиановая вики предлагает __NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia glxinfo

(а в арче ещё добавляют _VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only)

@andreymal Всё заработало, спасибо большое. но есть ли возможность, чтобы автоматически определяло, что запускать с дискретки, а что нет или каждый раз придётся прописывать?

Не слышал о такой возможности. Но как минимум вы можете насоздавать себе ярлыки с прописанными в них нужными переменными https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Desktop_entries_(Русский)#Изменение_переменных_окружения

(вообще, арч вот вынес прописывание этих переменных в отдельный bash-скриптик prime-run для удобства, не знаю почему дебиан не делает так же, впрочем, такой скриптик тоже можно создать самостоятельно)

@andreymal Хорошо. Можешь оставить ответ, так как вопрос решён.
